# react native android scroll view not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a react native component like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

import Level from './Level';

class LevelList extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} >
                <View style={styles.levelList}>
                    <Level />
                    <Level />
                    <Level />
                    <Level />
                    <Level />
                    <Level />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1,
    },
    levelList: {
        marginTop: 50,
        flexDirection:'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

})

export default LevelList;
```

Here `<Level>` is simply a component that holds a text.

I have `<LevelList>` in my container like:

```
class LevelListView extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Header />
                <LevelList />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default LevelListView
```

Here I get a scrollbar in the side of my list but it does not get scrolled.
What am I missing here ?

I am running the app in emulator:

**Update:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.toolbar}>
                <Text style={styles.toolbarBack}>Back</Text>
                <Text style={styles.toolbarTitle}>Levels</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    toolbar:{
        backgroundColor:'#00bcd4',
        paddingTop:10,
        paddingBottom:10,
        flexDirection:'row'
    },
    toolbarTitle:{
        color:'#fff',
        textAlign:'center',
        fontSize:20,
        fontWeight:'bold',
        marginRight: 30,
        flex:1
    },
    toolbarBack: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginTop: 4,
        marginLeft: 10,
    }
})

export default Header;
```

Comment: Hey, share 'Header' component code..

Comment: @Jickson I have added the Header component

Comment: Hey, I tried your code.. Its working here. Issue is in some other component i guess..

Comment: @Jickson I have only 2 component out there header and levellist.... You tried on emulator ??

Comment: Yes. I have tried on Android emulator..

Comment: @Jickson I figured out the issue but no solution. In my home page it is working.. the same component but after routing in the routed page scroll view is not working.. Not only scroll component touch opacity is also not working.. It works only on home page i.e to the page not being routed to anywhere

Comment: Ok.. Update the question with new issue and code related to that issue. Hopefully I will be able to help you

Comment: @Jickson I have created new question for the issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456641/react-native-scroll-view-do-not-work-after-routing-from-react-native-router-redu you can check it

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and tried everything on the internet like flex:1 solutions... But the problem is, Android is not letting you use nested scroll with scrollview. I just put:

```
nestedScrollEnabled={true}
```

Command to my scrollview object and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem but I resolved it by doing this:

```
<ScrollView style={{ 

    height:Dimensions.get('screen').height

    }}>
       ///
    </ScrollView>
```